# Highlight some rows and create them link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have this table. I want highlight some points which is have start in status and create them link when user click on these like the rows value send to the text box and delete the upper all rows using Javascript and jQuery

```
<table border="1px" style="font-size: 16px; height: 700px; overflow: auto;" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Enable</th>
            <th>S No</th>
            <th>Stop Name</th>
            <th>Longitude</th>
            <th>Latitude</th>
            <th>ETA</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>MaxFort School, Parwana Road</td>
        <td>28.69180</td>
        <td>77.10969</td>
        <td>09:33:45</td>
        <td>Ignition_On</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Edit'   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>MaxFort School, Parwana Road</td>
        <td>28.69182</td>
        <td>77.10970</td>
        <td>09:33:52</td>
        <td>Location</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Edit'   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>MaxFort School, Parwana Road</td>
        <td>28.69179</td>
        <td>77.10968</td>
        <td>09:34:19</td>
        <td>Ignition_On</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Edit'   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>MaxFort School, Parwana Road</td>
        <td>28.69178</td>
        <td>77.10968</td>
        <td>09:34:29</td>
        <td>Start</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Edit'   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>MaxFort School, Parwana Road</td>
        <td>28.69176</td>
        <td>77.10969</td>
        <td>09:34:39</td>
        <td>Stop</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Edit'   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>MaxFort School, Parwana Road</td>
        <td>28.69175</td>
        <td>77.10970</td>
        <td>09:34:49</td>
        <td>Ignition_On</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Edit'   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>MaxFort School, Parwana Road</td>
        <td>28.69178</td>
        <td>77.10971</td>
        <td>09:34:59</td>
        <td>Ignition_On</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Edit'   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>MaxFort School, Parwana Road</td>
        <td>28.69177</td>
        <td>77.10970</td>
        <td>09:35:09</td>
        <td>Ignition_On</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Edit'   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>MaxFort School, Parwana Road</td>
        <td>28.69179</td>
        <td>77.10970</td>
        <td>09:35:19</td>
        <td>Ignition_On</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Edit'   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>MaxFort School, Parwana Road</td>
        <td>28.69180</td>
        <td>77.10970</td>
        <td>09:35:29</td>
        <td>Ignition_On</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Edit'   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>MaxFort School, Parwana Road</td>
        <td>28.69181</td>
        <td>77.10971</td>
        <td>09:35:38</td>
        <td>Ignition_On</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Edit'   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>MaxFort School, Parwana Road</td>
        <td>28.69180</td>
        <td>77.10972</td>
        <td>09:35:48</td>
        <td>Start</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Edit'   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>MaxFort School, Parwana Road</td>
        <td>28.69177</td>
        <td>77.10973</td>
        <td>09:35:58</td>
        <td>Stop</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Edit'   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>MaxFort School, Parwana Road</td>
        <td>28.69176</td>
        <td>77.10974</td>
        <td>09:36:08</td>
        <td>Ignition_On</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Edit'   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>MaxFort School, Parwana Road</td>
        <td>28.69178</td>
        <td>77.10976</td>
        <td>09:36:18</td>
        <td>Start</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Edit'   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>MaxFort School, Parwana Road</td>
        <td>28.69181</td>
        <td>77.10979</td>
        <td>09:36:28</td>
        <td>Ignition_On</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Edit'   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>MaxFort School, Parwana Road</td>
        <td>28.69183</td>
        <td>77.10992</td>
        <td>09:36:38</td>
        <td>Moving</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Edit'   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>MaxFort School, Parwana Road</td>
        <td>28.69178</td>
        <td>77.11033</td>
        <td>09:36:48</td>
        <td>Moving</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Edit'   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>MaxFort School, Parwana Road</td>
        <td>28.69178</td>
        <td>77.11100</td>
        <td>09:36:58</td>
        <td>Moving</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Edit'   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>MaxFort School, Parwana Road</td>
        <td>28.69177</td>
        <td>77.11173</td>
        <td>09:37:06</td>
        <td>Depart</td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Edit'   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Share the JavaScript code whatever you tried else it will need a lots of work to make editable row.

Comment: I already did editable table . it is route  Management system the client want user select the starting point of the route . where status is start rows will highlight and at right side of row generate a div which is ask is this your starting point when user is select this all upper row were delete

Comment: Then you can use datagrid

Comment: ohky in jsp ..there any open source datagrid which is full fill my requirement

Comment: http://jquery-plugins.net/paramquery-grid-jquery-grid-plugin

Comment: http://www.programming-free.com/2013/02/gridview-in-java-using-jquery-datatable.html